# Last rewrite rule not working

Tags: .htaccess

Hi please I need some help here. I can only get the first rule to work, but the second rule does not work. If I switch the second rule to the first, it works fine. Basically the last rule doesn't work.
I hope to achieve something like this...
http://www.example.com/Name ...for both of them. Notwithstanding the php file name I specify.

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.html$ /mark.php?mart=$1 [L]
    RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.html$ /mark2.php?shop=$1 [L]
```

Comment: It doesn't process your second rule because the regular expression is *exactly* the same as the first.

Comment: Hi Josh, can you please give me an example of another regular expression i could use to achieve this. As I am not very keen with the mod_rewrite scripts. Thanks alot.

Answer (score 2):

The second rule isn't being processed because you specify the [L] (last rule) flag. So as the first rule applies, apache stops processing rules.

You can see more info about L flag here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_l

Anyway, as Josh said, the second rule is the same as the first one...